# Using a customed class as keys to in HashMap but not able to search the keys

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I created a HashMap that uses a customed class Location as keys. 
After inserting all the entries into the HashMap using `put()`, I am not able to search the keys.

I have tried to use `get()` or `containsKey()` to search, but neither give me positive results. However, I am sure that the keys do exists in the code because I have used HashMap iteration to print out the keys.

Below is the code:

```
public HashMap<Location, Integer>beenTo = new HashMap<>();
public int uniquePathsIII(int[][] grid) {
        for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
             for (int j=0; j<grid[0].length; j++){
                 if (grid[i][j] == 0 || grid[i][j] == 2){
                     Location newSquare = new Location(i,j);
                     notBeen.put(newSquare, 1);                    
                 }           
             }
        }
        Location newSquare = new Location(0,1);
        if (notBeen.get(newSquare) != null){
             return 10;
         }
        if (notBeen.isEmpty()){
            return -1;
        }
}
```

Below is the class Location:

```
class Location{
        int i;  // row  
        int j;  // column
        public Location(int _i, int _j){
            i = _i;
            j = _j;
        }
        public int getI(){
            return i;
        }
        public int getJ(){
            return j;
        }
        public void setI(int _i){
            i = _i;
        }
        public void setJ(int _j){
            j = _j;
        }
}
```

In the above code, I wanted to search for the key `Location(0,1)`. I have made sure that the Hashmap `notBeen` is not empty, and tried that the key does exist. But I am never able to find it using `containsKey()` nor `get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement/override `hashCode` and `equals` methods if you want a custom Object to work as a key in a HashMap in Java.

FYI:
`_variableName` goes against Java naming conventions [Oracle Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). It is also not necessary as you can get the same result using:

```
public Location(int i, int j){
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I have tried to override the `equals()` method of my location class. However, the `HashMap.get()` method still cannot find the object. Does that mean I should override the `get()` method?

Comment: I just override the `hashCode()` method of my `Location` class. The `containsKey()` and `get()` methods both work fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid memory leaks map's key must be immutable object,and improve search key speed,the key object has equals() and hashcode() methods is good practice(first use hashcode judge equals then use equals() method).In your code it is best to make location immutable(not support setter methods).

```
public class Location {
    private final int i;
    private final int j;

    public Location(int x, int y) {
        this.i = x;
        this.j = y;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Location)) {
            return false;
        }
        Location point = (Location) o;
        return i == point.i &&
            j == point.j;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(i, j);
    }
}
```